# Upgrading Magento 2

Tags: magento2, upgrade, patches

With Magento 1 when I needed to apply a security patch I just did it locally and then pushed changes to remote repository and pulled them on production.

What about Magento 2? If the installation on production was made via composer then I need to do it on production server via [command line](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html)?

Do I locally do the first step

```
composer require <product> <version> --no-update
composer update
```

and then push the updated composer file to repository and pull changes on production and continue with commands in the guide (so that same code base is on local, remote repository and production)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question depends on how you are using your source control for the Magento core code.

1) If you are using your own repo for all the Magento code then you will want to do it locally, commit the changes to your repo and deploy.

2) If you are using composer then you should already have a deployment build procedure in place to account for changes to any code. For example, you should run your build on a build server which would include all your composer updates, then commit this build to an artifact repository and deploy that build to your production server.

Comment: Nice to see you after long time.